# MySQL with Nodd js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating a rest api that uses mysql as data base. My confusion is that should i connect to database in every request and release the connection at the end of the operation. Or should i connect the database at the start of the server and make it globally available and forget about releasing the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would caution that neither option is quite wise.

The advantage of creating one connection for each request is that those connections can interact with your database in parallel, this is great when you have a lot of requests coming through.

The disadvantage (and the reason you might just create one connection on startup and share it) is obviously the setup cost of establishing a new connection each time.

One option to look into is connection pooling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool.

At a high level you can establish a pool of open connections on startup. When you need to make a request remove one of those connections from the pool, use it, and return it when done.

There are a number of useful Node packages that implement this abstraction, you should be able to find one if you look.